# A time.Parse Error, What am I doing wrong?

Tags: datetime, parsing, go

I'm running into the most bizarre issue regarding datestring parsing in golang using the time package.

The Error:

```
parsing time "07-20-2018" as "2006-01-02": cannot parse "0-2018" as "2006"
```

The Code Block:

```
log.Println(datestring) //07-20-2018
date, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02", datestring)
log.Println(err) //parsing time "07-20-2018" as "2006-01-02": cannot parse "0-2018" as "2006"
log.Println(date) //parsing time "07-20-2018" as "2006-01-02": cannot parse "0-2018" as "2006"
```

I'm completely at a loss to what this issue is referring to, the string is parsed from the URI in golang with gorilla mux.

```
datestring, _ := vars["date"] //some/path/{date}, date is 07-20-2018
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is obvious. You are trying to parse mm-dd-yyyy as yyyy-mm-dd.

---

A simple fix:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    datestring := "07-20-2018"
    fmt.Println(datestring)
    date, err := time.Parse("01-02-2006", datestring)
    fmt.Println(date, err)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/gK7cMAkrP7l

Output:

```
07-20-2018
2018-07-20 00:00:00 +0000 UTC <nil>
```

---

See Go [Package time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/).

Comment: Thank you! I did not realize the input for Parse is supposed to be the format of the input time, not the format of the output you want the date to be in.

Comment: @BrandonHawkinson: `time.Parse` requires an input format so that is can resolve ambiguities. For example, is "10-11-12" mm-dd-yy (US), dd-mm-yy (Europe), yy-mm-dd (ISO), etc.